# ElasticSearch - Java API indexing 100K + PDFs using producer & consumer

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Am indexing pdf using java api. I have installed ingest-attachement processor plugin and from my java code, am converting PDF into base64 and indexing encoded format of PDF.

Actually, PDFs are available in my machine d:\ drive. The file path are available in ElasticSearch index named as documents_local. So, am fetching all the records from documents_local index and getting the file path. Then, am reading the pdf file and encode into base64. Then indexing them.

For this process, am using scrollRequest API to fetch file path from index, because am having more that 100k documents. so, for indexing 20000 PDFs its taking 8 hours of time with the below java code.

So, i tried to seperated this process of indexing.

I have created 3 classses,

```
Controller.java
Producer.java
Consumer.java
```

From `Controller.java` class am reading all the filePath from my index and am storing all the filePath into ArrayList and passing to `Producer` class.

From `Producer.java` class am reading PDF using the filePath and converting into base64 and pushing into the `queue`.

From `Consumer.java` class i will read all the messages from the queue which are published by `producer.java` class.

My idea is, i want to index the encoded files in `Consumer.java` class. ( which is not implemented and am not sure how to do that).

Please find my java code below.

Controller.java

```
public class Controller {

    private static final int QUEUE_SIZE = 2;
    private static BlockingQueue<String> queue;
    private static Collection<Thread> producerThreadCollection, allThreadCollection;

    private final static String INDEX = "documents_local";  
    private final static String ATTACHMENT = "document_suggestion";
    private final static String TYPE = "doc";
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[0].getClassName());

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient = null;
        Document doc=new Document();
        List<String> filePathList = new ArrayList<String>();


        producerThreadCollection = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        allThreadCollection = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        queue = new LinkedBlockingDeque<String>(QUEUE_SIZE);

        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(INDEX); 
        searchRequest.types(TYPE);
        final Scroll scroll = new Scroll(TimeValue.timeValueMinutes(60L)); //part of Scroll API

        searchRequest.scroll(scroll); //part of Scroll API
        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery();

        searchSourceBuilder.query(qb);
        searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);


        SearchResponse searchResponse = SearchEngineClient.getInstance3().search(searchRequest);
        String scrollId = searchResponse.getScrollId(); //part of Scroll API
        SearchHit[] searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
        long totalHits=searchResponse.getHits().totalHits;
        logger.info("Total Hits --->"+totalHits);

        //part of Scroll API -- Starts
        while (searchHits != null && searchHits.length > 0) { 
            SearchScrollRequest scrollRequest = new SearchScrollRequest(scrollId); 
            scrollRequest.scroll(scroll);
            searchResponse = SearchEngineClient.getInstance3().searchScroll(scrollRequest);
            scrollId = searchResponse.getScrollId();
            searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();

            for (SearchHit hit : searchHits) {


                Map<String, Object> sourceAsMap = hit.getSourceAsMap();


                if(sourceAsMap != null) {  
                    doc.setId((int) sourceAsMap.get("id"));
                    doc.setApp_language(String.valueOf(sourceAsMap.get("app_language")));
               }

                filePathList.add(doc.getPath().concat(doc.getFilename()));
            }
        }


        createAndStartProducers(filePathList);
        createAndStartConsumers(filePathList);

        for(Thread t: allThreadCollection){
            try {
                t.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Controller finished");
    }

    private static void createAndStartProducers(List<String> filePathList){
        for(int i = 1; i <= filePathList.size(); i++){
            Producer producer = new Producer(Paths.get(filePathList.get(i)), queue);
            Thread producerThread = new Thread(producer,"producer-"+i);
            producerThreadCollection.add(producerThread);
            producerThread.start();
        }
        allThreadCollection.addAll(producerThreadCollection);
    }

    private static void createAndStartConsumers(List<String> filePathList){
        for(int i = 0; i < filePathList.size(); i++){
            Thread consumerThread = new Thread(new Consumer(queue), "consumer-"+i);
            allThreadCollection.add(consumerThread);
            consumerThread.start();
        }
    }

    public static boolean isProducerAlive(){
        for(Thread t: producerThreadCollection){
            if(t.isAlive())
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Producer.java

```
public class Producer implements Runnable {

     private Path fileToRead;
        private BlockingQueue<String> queue;
        File file=null;

        public Producer(Path filePath, BlockingQueue<String> q){
            fileToRead = filePath;
            queue = q;
        }

        public void run() {

                String encodedfile = null;

                BufferedReader reader = null;
                try {
                    reader = Files.newBufferedReader(fileToRead);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                File file=new File(reader.toString());

                if(file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()) {

                    try {

                        FileInputStream fileInputStreamReader = new FileInputStream(file);
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
                        fileInputStreamReader.read(bytes);
                        encodedfile = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes));
                        fileInputStreamReader.close();
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" finished");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("File not exists");

                }
        }


}
```

Consumer.java (uncompleted class, not sure how i can do index from consumer class , Just showing skeleton of my consumer class.)

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable {

     private BlockingQueue<String> queue;
     File file=null;

        public Consumer(BlockingQueue<String> q){
            queue = q;
        }

        public void run(){


            while(true){
                String line = queue.poll();

                if(line == null && !Controller.isProducerAlive())
                    return;

                if(line != null){
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" processing line: "+line);
                    //Do something with the line here like see if it contains a string
                }

            }
        }

}
```

With the below piece of code i have indexed the encoded file, But its taking more time to index because am having `100k` documents. So that am trying for `Producer` & `Consumer` concept

```
jsonMap = new HashMap<>();
jsonMap.put("id", doc.getId());
jsonMap.put("app_language", doc.getApp_language());
jsonMap.put("fileContent", result);

String id=Long.toString(doc.getId());

IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest(ATTACHMENT, "doc", id )
        .source(jsonMap)
        .setPipeline(ATTACHMENT);
```

Comment: Not a direct answer but did you look at FSCrawler? https://github.com/dadoonet/fscrawler

Comment: @dadoonet - Yes, i had a look., but its very complex for me to understand.

Comment: But did you try to just use it?